# Generate xml file and/or html html files of xml comments

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've commented my code (with three "///" at class-level and some methods), but as it as an exam, my teacher wants the documentation in my report.

Im wondering two things:

1. How to  generate xml file of my comments ?
2. Do anyone know if there exist a good program to generate html files of the xml documentation ? to get it as "javadoc" style...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Sandcastle Help File Builder](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) or use [Sandcastle](http://sandcastle.codeplex.com/) directly. I've only the used the Help File Builder in the past but I've heard that using Sandcastle directly can be cumbersome at times, although I don't know how accurate that is. [This tutorial](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/) might help.

Answer (score 1):

To get the file.

```
Right Click Project 
Select Properties
Select build tab,
```

at the bottom in the output section there's a `checkbox` called `Xml Documentation file`.

After you have that, style and transform as desired.